# Slide number does not appear in Power Point template

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I want use this [Power Point template](http://noorang.ir/files/download/type/p/id/177/tagid/26) but I am not able to insert page numbers in it. 
What is the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the links above is dead and the for other you require to login...
Therefore I show a summary of the method described in that link. This method was very useful for me!

1. Click **Slide Master** in the **View** tab and go to the template you want to change.
2. Insert a new **Text Box** on the location you want the slide number to appear.
3. Go with your cursor **IN** the text box. You can change the font if you like.
4. With your cursor in the text box go to the Insert tab and add a **Slide Number**. Something like <#> will appear. If you want some text if front, type it!
5. **Exit** the slide master mode. The slide number is now shown on the slides you used from the template. If you now add a new slide from the template the number should also be on it and will automatically be changed.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for spotting those bad links and getting an actual fix on this post. We'll see about cleaning up the answer which is no longer an answer.